# Reading Login data with delim

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have been trying to make a login interface where the user registers first into the system with some data like username, password, address, and email while using "-" as a delim between the data after storing them in a text file as below.

> user1-pass1-user1@gmail.com-1 New York city
>
> user2-pass2-user2@gmail.com-2 New York city

then using the code below I try to look for the username and password within the text but it only can extract the first line but not the second

```
void login()
{
    string User, Pass, ConfirmUser, ConfirmPass;
 
   cout << "Please Enter Your Name And Password to Login:\n";
        << "Username: ";
   getline(cin, User);
   cout << "Password: ";
   getline(cin, Pass);


   ifstream input("database.txt");
   while (input) {

       getline(input, u, '-');
       getline(input, p, '-');
        
       if (u == user && p == pass) {
           authenticated = true;
           system("cls");
           
       }
       input.close();
   }

   if (authenticated) {
        cout << "\nHello " << user << "\nLogin Sucsses!";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        
   }
   else {
        cout << "\nLogin Failed!\nPlease Check your Username and Password Again!";
        main();
   }
}
```

What do I need to do to get the code to check not only the first line of text but to check all of the text file as I will be adding more users?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `while (input)` loop, you have an `input.close()`.

So, naturally, no input will be accepted after the first iteration.

Perhaps this sort of mistake would be easier to spot, if you used consistent/sensible indentation.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to fix the issue tho, does getline() read all the lines ignoring whitespaces or it stops in this case at the end of the first line?

Comment: What does the documentation say on this?